# Can I access the raw payloads?

Tags: go, grpc

Under some circumstances I find myself needing to access the raw payload posted to either a grpc endpoint or to a gateway that exposes it for http1/REST. More specifically invalid payloads are sometimes posted and I have no way of logging the actual payload posted by the client since the struct passed to the handler will only capture the expected bits from the request payload.

I don't see anything in the context object passed to my handler funcs that would allow one to access the original, unadulterated payload. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you tell us the libraries (with versions) you use and maybe provide some code snippets please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.